# How can I leave every answer from 'for'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I think my code works well.
But the problem is that my code does not leave every answer on DataFrame R.
When I print R, only the last answer appeared.
What should I do to display every answer?
I want to add answer on the next column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


DATA = pd.DataFrame()
DATA = pd.read_excel('C:\gskim\P4DS/Monthly Stock adjClose2.xlsx')
DATA = DATA.set_index("Date")             

DATA1 = np.log(DATA/DATA.shift(1))                             
DATA2 = DATA1.drop(DATA1.index[0])*100                         


F = pd.DataFrame(index = DATA2.index)
for i in range (0, 276):
    Q = DATA2.iloc[i].dropna()
    W = sorted(abs(Q), reverse = False)
    W_qcut = pd.qcut(W, 5, labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
    F = Q.groupby(W_qcut).sum()
    R = pd.DataFrame(F)
    print(R)
```

the first table is the current result, I want to fill every blank tables on the second table as a result:

[image]

Comment: Can you give examples of the data you are working with and the final shape you would like it to take please?

Comment: DATA2 is monthly Stock returns. I ordered returns on the size of volatility. And I grouped returns into 5 groups at W_qcut. The final shape is that A, B, C, D, E on the columns and DATA2.index on columns which is Date.

Comment: Yes can you give us a minimal example of the data in the code before processing and then how it looks after processing and how you want it to look

Comment: Umm I added the picture of shape which I want but I cannot see it on the web. Please check my previous codes.

Comment: Oh, while I am asking the question I found what I wanted. Thanks!